# 2 problems. Trouble saving form data into database (has a dynamic drop down box) & I need two text fields to update based on drop box selection

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

OK thank you for checking my post, i would like to say I am pretty new to mysql and php and i really appreciate your help!.

I have two tables. Employee (Employee_ID, First_name, Last_name, Address etc) and Training (Training_ID, Employee_ID, First_name, Last_name, Training_type).

For the training table, I have a form in which is meant to be filled out to assign a training type for an employee.

In the training form, i have just managed to insert a drop down box which contains the values of 'employee_id' from the employee table. HOWEVER, ever since i have added this, it wont let me submit the form and save the data into my database. so if you could tell me what is wrong with my code that would be GREAT.

Lastly, isit possible to update two text fields (first_name, Last_name) from the form when the user id changes in the drop down box from the form? I have searched everywhere and am struggling to find this. Below is my PHP code.

```
<html>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("hrmwaitrose", $con);
?>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<title>Training</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="content">  
<h1 align="center">Add Training</h1>

<form action="inserttraining.php" method="post">
<div>
<p>Training ID: <input type="text" name="Training_ID"></p>
<p>Employee ID:<select id="Employee_ID">
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Employee_ID FROM Employee");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "<option value=$row[0]>$row[0]</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<p>First name: <input type="text" name="First_name"></p>
<p>Last name: <input type="text" name="Last_name"></p>
<p>
Training required?
<select name="Training">
<option value="">Select...</option>
<option value="Customer Service">Customer Service</option>
<option value="Bailer">Bailer</option>
<option value="Reception">Reception</option>
<option value="Fish & meat counters">Fish & meat counters</option>
<option value="Cheese counters">Cheese counters</option>
</select>
</p>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is my php code for when the submit button is pressed.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("hrmwaitrose", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO training (Training_ID, Employee_ID, First_name, Last_name, Training)
VALUES
 ('$_POST[Training_ID]','$_POST[Employee_ID]','$_POST[First_name]','$_POST[Last_name]','$_POST[Training]')";


if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Ever since I changed my employee ID to a dynamic drop down box it has not been sending data to database, so i think it is to do with that. sorry if my code is all over the place, as i said i am pretty new to this!!! and i would like to thank you in advance as i am having so much trouble with this!!!

Comment: Learn prepared statements instead of the old mysql_* things so you learn it the right way. This will most likely also solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add the name attribute in your select, therefore the form is not sending the input (select) value.

```
<select id="Employee_ID" name="Employee_ID">
```

Comment: cheers thank you. do you know how to update text fields based on the selection of the drop down box by any chance?

Comment: Sure, but ask a new question please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142583/populate-text-fields-in-form-based-on-value-selected-from-dynamic-drop-down-bo